# Old process is still running when there is a new search

Tags: python, google-maps, twitter, process, tweepy

I am building a web-application in HTML,js and python tweepy in back-end where user can see live tweets on a map based on a hashtag search.

The issue is if user put new search and behind python old process still running, new user could see old results too, How could i close old process.when there is a new search???

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but why don't you make a listener for a new search which terminates the already running search process?

Comment: Try detailing your problem statement.